# PHP + SQLi - Auto incrementing ID's

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment

I've come across a problem where in my PHP, for some reason I have to define what the ID is or I get my "die" message, even though the table structure is set to auto increment, here is my PHP:

```
$query = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO users (username, email, passhash, reg_ip, reg_date, salt)VALUES('$username','$email','$pass1','$ip_address',now(),'$salt')") or die("Could not create your account, please try again later.");
```

ID is currently not in that code, and it isn't working, if I were to do:

```
$id = 1;
```

and then add it to the insert, it works, for some reason I can't set it as NULL either.

Structure: bigint, unsigned, auto-increment, primary key.

Comment: Have you defined the id as "AUTO_INCREMENT" when creating the table?

Comment: What mysql error gets generated?  Use mysqli_errno and mysqli_error to get the errors.

Comment: Yes, ticked A_I on phpmyadmin.

Comment: Where about in the code would I put "mysqli_error" at? Just tried underneath the insert and it didn't read any errors.

Comment: You'd replace the or die with it.

Comment: Notice: Use of undefined constant mysqli_error - assumed 'mysqli_error' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/register.php on line 38

Comment: try to insert from php myadmin manual without assign any value to id

Comment: try looking it up in the manual.  mysqli_errno and mysqli_error aren't constants, they're functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reset the auto-increment value back to 1, as you've hit the limit.

```
ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT = 1 ;
```

Comment: Ok then as others have suggested, you do not have the auto_increment value set on your database table. If you're able to run this query, please provide the output. `select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables where table_name = 'users';`

Comment: For auto-increment, it returns this: 18446744073709551615

Comment: that's the problem, you've hit the max auto_increment value, try resetting it back to 1 ... mysql will then set it to the lowest value it can.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you modify your query like this :

```
INSERT INTO users (id ,username, email, passhash, reg_ip, reg_date, salt)
VALUES            (null,'$username','$email','$pass1','$ip_address',now(),'$salt')
```

Try it this way,it should add the id as an auto increment.

Comment: you could also remove `id` completely from the query and null as the 'value'

Comment: Isn't that just the same except with null set for ID? I've already tried null like I said above, still get the die message. Also tried it without ID being defined, doesn't work.

Comment: If the id is an auto_increment column, then if you insert it as null or if you don't mention it at all, there shouldn't be any errors. Check your table structure it the above example doesn't work.

Comment: id bigint(4)  UNSIGNED      NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: If you have something like this : CREATE TABLE new_table ( id bigint(4) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (id) ) You can insert values with this : insert into new_table values() -- without any field or value declarations or you could use : insert into new_table (`id`) values (null) or you could just use insert into new_table values (null) - they all work.